# Retrieve data from sqlite and preview it

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a button when I press it , I start a new activity `myActivity`. I want the layout of `myActivity` to preview some data retrieved from `myDataBase`, but when I change the text of `TextView` the program crash , here is my code.

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {

TextView tv1;
myDataBase DB;
String s;
String reqName
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.information);
    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.testtest);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    reqName = bundle.getString("someKey");
        DB = new myDataBase(this);
    new GetSomeData().execute(reqName);
}
public class GetSomeData extends AsyncTask<String,Integer ,String>
{
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try
    {
    String name = reqName;
    DB.open();
    s = DB.getData(name);
    DB.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace();

    }

    tv1.setText(s);  // this line makes the program crash
    return s;

}   
}}
```

I think the program crash because of cross threading (I am not sure!),
How can I solve this problem? Is there a better idea for previewing the data from the data base?

Comment: we can't create any UI in the doInBackground() method of AsyncTask<>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not allowed to modify UI elements from a background thread. An `AsyncTasks`'s `doInBackground()` method runs in a background thread, so that's why you're getting an error.

Instead, return the `String` you wish to set to the `TextView` from your `doInBackground()` method to the `onPostExecute()` method, then set that `String` to your `TextView` there. This works, because `onPostExecute()` runs in the main thread, also known as the "UI thread".

```
public class GetSomeData extends AsyncTask<String,Integer ,String> {
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      try {
         String name = reqName;
         DB.open();
         s = DB.getData(name);
         DB.close();
      } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return s;
   } 

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute (String s) {
      tv1.setText(s);
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much,,, i solved this problem before in c# by `this.invoke()`methode